# How to scan hidden Audio/ Video files (starts with "." dot)?

Tags: java, android, hidden-files

I've tried many things for loading hidden media files in android and I've successfully loaded hidden files but the problem is how to get the additional details like audio file album, video file thumbnail, duration etc.

I've seen the link below but it's not helpful in loading additional details of media files.

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Hidden-File-Scanner

Comment: I suppose you're using MediaStore. How does you query looks like? Since I'm pretty sure hidden files are included in `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns`